# How to find a root note of an unknown scale?

Tags: scales

I can pick a pentatonic scale by ear to play along the song but I dont know what would be the root of the scale and if its in  major or minor.

Comment: Don't try to figure out keys by fitting pentatonic scales; since pentatonics are diatonic scales which are missing some notes, they can fit multiple keys. Because of this, it is relatively easy to play something using a pentatonic scale that doesn't sound obviously wrong when you don't know what key you are in.

Comment: So my knowledge is absolutely useless. Thanks for pointing it out. What should I do then? Learn each existing scale?

Comment: Learn about keys; learn the major scale thoroughly in every key (this means learn how to play it and learn what it sounds like, for starters). There are lots of questions on SE Music about figuring out what key a tune is in, like [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26912/how-can-i-figure-out-the-key-of-the-song-im-writing-on-the-guitar), or [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/how-to-figure-out-what-key-a-piece-is-in).

Comment: I do know major and minor scale and pentatonic is very easy and fun to play on guitar, I can learn the major and minor forms as well and even pick the correct one by ear. Is it possible to find a root note then or it's just possible when you learn how each scale sounds like by heart?

Comment: The root note should usually be the one that you hear the piece "tend towards" or "come home to". I usually find It's possible to find it very instinctively without much conscious thought, but learning scales will sharpen those instincts.

Comment: The "root" note of a pentatonic scale is determined by context, the same way the root note of a fully diminished seventh chord is determined by context. The notes can be arranged in a number of ways and be given different names. What they are has to do with the music that is going on around it. That will point to which note sounds like "home." One could say the same thing about all the modes. If I have notes from C-C with no sharps or flats, how do I know whether I am in major or natural minor or dorian or another mode? Context.

Answer (score 4):

The root note of any scale is the one that sounds most at rest - or at home. The one that could end the piece. Particularly playing the tonic chord (which is based on the root note), will help you to establish which it is. Often pieces will start, as well as end on that tonic.

There may well be a problem with the pentatonics, as guitarists (in particular) like to play the minor pent. over major chords. Nothing wrong there - it's just that a lot of guitarists only ever use that minor pent. and are maybe unaware that a major pent. exists. Take A minor pent. The same five notes also become the C major pent. But with a different root, obviously. A minor pent. will work happily over A major pieces, but so will A major pent. A major pent. is made up from the same five notes as F♯ minor pent.

As others urge - learn major scales - on guitar, one pattern can be moved up and down to produce all twelve, so not a daunting task! I recommend starting with A major, 5th fret bottom string, and work up to 5th fret top string (A). By using frets 4-7, it'll all be done without sliding the hand up or down. That pattern will then do for all major scales - C, for instance, starts on fret 8.